# Convergence of $x_{n+1} = c\cdot x_n^2-2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Consider the sequence $\langle x_n\rangle $, $n\ge 0$, defined by the recurrence relation 
>   $$x_{n+1} = c \cdot x_n^2 - 2, \quad\text{where $c > 0$.}$$
>   Suppose there exists a non-empty, open interval $(a,b)$ such that for all $x_0$ satisfying $a < x_0 < b$, the sequence converges to a limit. The sequence converges to a value.
>
> A. $(1+\sqrt{1+8c})/2c$
>
> B. $(1-\sqrt{1+8c})/2c$
>
> C. $2$
>
> D. $2/(2c - 1)$

I was trying this problem by putting random values for $c$ and $x_0$ like if $c=1$ and $x_0 = -1$ then the sequence becomes $-1, -1, -1, \dots$ and thus the sequence converges to $-1$. So, I am getting option B as correct.

And again if $c = 1$ and $x_0 = 2$ then the sequence becomes $2,2,2,\dots$ and thus the sequence converges to $2$. So, I am getting option A as correct.

Among the 4 options only one can be correct. They have given option B as correct answer. I don't know how to solve this. Please help.

Comment: You were using a weird mix of MathJax and normal text in your formulas, I changed everything to MathJax. Make sure your post is still how you intended it and read our [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not consider the given condition for $x_0$. There has to be an open interval $(a,b)$ with $x_0\in(a,b)$ such that the sequence converges for all initial values in $(a,b)$. For $c=1$ and $x_0=2$ there is no such interval since any $x_0'>2$ will give a divergent sequence.

---

Note that the map $x\mapsto cx^2-2$ will always have two fixed points, so those will occur as limits of your sequence. However, at most one of the two fixed points will be [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory), so that for initial values near the fixed point your sequence converges to the fixed point.